# Property field return nulls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My server/client side application has following controllers. However when I post/create a reservation, it does not the hold/cache the value of (id) property return  `(CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById)`, `new{id=order.id}, order}` method, when post action goes out of scope. Therefore `GetById(int id)` does not receive last id generated rather shows 0. However data commits successfully in the database with valid id.

**Server side controller:**

```
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
            public ActionResult<OrderTable> GetById(int id)
            {
                var order = _context.ReservationsTables.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
                if(order == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    return order;
                }
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult<OrderTable> CreateOrder(OrderTable order)
            {           
                _context.ReservationsTables.Add(order);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = order.Id }, order);
            }
```

**Client Side controller:**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePostAsync(OrderTable order)
            {
                var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:44387/api/Reservation", order);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var orderResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrderTable>();
                    return RedirectToAction("ThankYouAsync", new { id = order.Id });
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("An error has occurred");
                }
            }
            public async Task<IActionResult> ThankYouAsync(int orderId)
            {
                var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44387/");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/Reservation/" + orderId);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var orderResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrderTable>();
                    return View(orderResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("An error has occurred");
                }
            }


 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            await PopulateRestaurantDropDownListAsync();
            return View();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The redirected action has the following signature

```
Task<IActionResult> ThankYouAsync(int orderId)
```

Note that the parameter name is `orderId`.

Yet when the redirection is done,

```
return RedirectToAction("ThankYouAsync", new { id = order.Id });
```

the value object is defined `new { id = order.Id }`

The parameter names need to match for it to work as expected.

So update `RedirectToAction` to use the correct property name

```
return RedirectToAction("ThankYouAsync", new { orderId = order.Id });
```

Note the `new { orderId = order.Id }` in the value object with matching `orderId` parameter.